# Wordpress WP_editor() HTML formatting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, formatting

I'm working today on an Wordpress plugin with the beautiful WP_Editor()

But this editor doesn't format their HTML, every time i add some html text with the editor and save it correctly as an posts in the database, is everything fine. but when i post this html string data to my WP_Editor() it messed it up.

Is their an solution to get the right format to view html in the wp_editor?

thanks a lot!

P.s. my code:

```
$settings_desc = array(
   'textarea_name' => 'description',
   'mode' => 'specific_textareas',
   'editor_selector' => 'theEditor',
   'width' => '100%',
   'theme' => 'advanced',
   'skin' => 'wp_theme',
   'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,link,unlink,wp_more,|,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv',
   'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'formatselect,underline,justifyfull,forecolor,|,pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,media,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,wp_help',
   'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
   'theme_advanced_buttons4' => '',
   'language' => 'de',
   'spellchecker_languages' => 'English=en,Danish=da,Dutch=nl,Finnish=fi,French=fr,+German=de,Italian=it,Polish=pl,Portuguese=pt,Spanish=es,Swedish=sv',
   'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top',
   'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'left',
   'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom',
   'theme_advanced_resizing' => true,
   'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal' => false,
   'dialog_type' => 'modal',
   'relative_urls' => false,
   'remove_script_host' => false,
   'convert_urls' => false,
   'apply_source_formatting' => false,
   'remove_linebreaks' => true,
   'gecko_spellcheck' => true,
   'entities' => '38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',
   'accessibility_focus' => true,
   'tabfocus_elements' => 'major-publishing-actions',
   'media_strict' => false,
   'paste_remove_styles' => true,
   'paste_remove_spans' => true,
   'paste_strip_class_attributes' => 'all',
   'wpeditimage_disable_captions' => false,
   'plugins' => 'safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker,paste,wordpress,media,fullscreen,wpeditimage,wpgallery,tabfocus',
 );
```

Comment: Please refrain from expletives in your posts [as noted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233)

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there an solution ?